# How to make ansi-term exit automatically once emacs exits?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Each time i press C-x-C-c to exit emacs, it always want me be sure whether or not close the shell process spawned by ansi-term.  Can i make ansi-term exit unconditionally once emacs exit ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 1):

Check `(set-process-query-on-exit-flag PROCESS FLAG)` and set `process-query-on-exit-flag` variable to nil for  `ansi-term` process.

Add `(set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil)` to `term-exec` function in term.el.

```
;; Crank up a new process
(let ((proc (term-exec-1 name buffer command switches)))
  (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil)        <------------here
  (make-local-variable 'term-ptyp)
```